# Tiles not Rendering/Exposing Evenly

Tags: rendering

Working on a bathroom arch viz project and running into an issue with the tiles not rendering evenly, specifically on the walls, doors, and ceiling. [image: Pano Rendering] There are dark squares that are not exposed like the tiles around them. I've noticed this in all images rendered with this project, not just this image.

Render settings are changed slightly from the default but I've played around with those and haven't seen any difference.

Any thoughts on how to go about fixing this issue?

Comment: Posting screenshots of the render settings would be helpful. I think if you could post a stripped down version of the .blend file with all the assets that you don't want/cannot share removed but with the issue reproducible, the chances of getting a good answer would increase as well.